# Conditional probabilities and order of operation

Tags: probability

I see terms of the form $P(A|B,C)$ a fair bit. Which of the following is true?

1. $P(A|B,C)$ is the joint probability of $A|B$ and $C$
2. $P(A|B,C)$ is the probability of $A$ given both $B$ and $C$

Comment: The second reading would make little sense as "given $B$" would necessarily apply to both $A$ and $C$. i.e. this would rather produce $P((A\cap C)|B)$.

Comment: The first reading you mean? Yes, I see - thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the second. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

$\Pr(A|B,C)$ is an abbreviation for $\Pr(A|(B\cap C))$.